# Office 365 ProPlus, does it support VBA Excel Macro?

Tags: excel

**Office 365 ProPlus**, does it support **VBA Excel Macro**?

I have a lot of macro applications running in version 2013 but if I have Office 365 ProPlus installed on my PC, can I use existing macros or develop macros in this O365ProPlus?

Thanks for the answers. :)

Comment: Displaying xlsm on the web & mobile version of the Office is supported, though none of the macro will run. But the *desktop* app version always fully support macros, regardless of your version/subscription

Comment: Try downloading the [Readiness Toolkit for Office add-ins and VBA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55983).  That will tell you for sure.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your answer my questions.